# Trouble defining inter-table relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm

### Goal

I am trying to setup a simple `has_many` association with Gorm: a person has many pets.

### Problem

I see the following error when I try to save the `Person` model.

> unsupported type []model.Pet, a slice of struct

### Details

Assume I want to save an `Person` that has many `Pets`.

```
type Person struct {
    UUID `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY" json:"uuid"`
    Pet  []Pet `gorm:"foreignkey:PersonUUID:association_foreignkey:UUID"`
}

type Pet struct {
    UUID `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY" json:"uuid"`
  PersonUUID string
}
```

Then I try to create these two models.

```
personUUID := "dcf4b3c6-d94c-4b2c-9d66-1cbaedd2cc44"
pets := []Pet{
  Pet{
    UUID: "..",
    PersonUUID: personUUID,
  }
}
person := Person{
  UUID: personUUID,
  Pet: Pet,
}

db.Where("uuid = ?", person.UUID).Update(&person)
```

Then I get the following error.

```
sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []model.Pet, a slice of struct
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190139/discussion-between-flimzy-and-maximus-s).

Answer (score 0):

I found out it only happens if you use `Update` instead of `Save`.
This is odd, because both should work the same way except that `Update` will try to save the different fields while `Save` will replace the current values with the new values.